# How Small Can a Planet be with 1G Gravity and Tectonics?

Tags: planets, hard-science, gravity, astronomy, tectonics

Without resorting to solid osmium inner cores that we couldn't give an origin story for, what's a cosmologically plausible lower bound of a planet's radius that also maintains 1G gravity and the sort of mantle conditions you need for plate tectonics?

Answer (score 5):

Using the same methodology I used in my answer to *[How Big Can a Habitable Planet Get Before Its Gravity is More Than 0.8 m/s² above Earth's 9.81 m/s²?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/197990/how-big-can-a-habitable-planet-get-before-its-gravity-is-more-than-0-8-m-s%C2%B2-abov/198015#198015)* I've made the following table. The last line is data for Earth.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVCRo.png]

A planet that has a radius that is 0.62 the Earth radius and 0.3836 the mass of the Earth will have a surface gravity very close to $g$ and an average density of 8.876 t/m<sup>3</sup> (g/cm<sup>3</sup>). This density is very close to the density of [Kepler-10b](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/multimedia/images/kepler10b_images.html).

All that is needed for plate tectonics are [significant oceans](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2001AGUFM.U21A..09S/abstract) above the subducting plates so water can lubricate the plates during subduction.

Comment: dont forget that plates also require an active core thats hot enough and moving around often enough to keep the plates from settling too soon

Comment: What I was thinking would be an issue for plate tectonics is the requirements for mantle fluidity. Otherwise you can just stipulate a relatively pure iron planet (or hell, even a chthonian. It takes quite a while for those to bounce back to hydrostatic equilibrium). Would that not be an issue?

Comment: @MaximalDestrier: You are correct.